# Google Script: adding up arrays

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to write a google spreadsheet with two main parts: an individual order form to calculate price & a system to count the total orders.

I made a simplified version here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_vRnX-qT3-0puYhtBCclYIVu504A-donE4nU8rQn41k/edit?usp=sharing

After noting an individual order and the order is paid, the green button is clicked. The button activates the payment-script.

The payment script needs to add the values of the individual order to the total orders and afterwards empty the individual orders.

```
function payment() {

  var individualOrder = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E3:E6').getValues();
  var currentTotal = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('O3:O6').getValues();
  var newTotal = [0,0,0,0];

  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    newTotal[i] = currentTotal[i] + individualOrder[i];
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('O3:O6').setValues([newTotal]);

  // Reset individual order after payment
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E3:E6').setValue(0);

}
```

EDIT: Now it does work to replace the new Total values by using the code below, but there is another problem. When summing the array values 1 + 0, it cocatenates them to 10 instead of using math-values. Any ideas?

```
function payment() {

  var individualOrder = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E3:E6').getValues();
  var currentTotal = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('O3:O6').getValues();
  var newTotal = currentTotal;

  Logger.log(individualOrder);
  Logger.log(currentTotal);

  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    newTotal[i] = [currentTotal[i] + individualOrder[i]];
  }

  Logger.log(newTotal);

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('O3:O6').setValues(newTotal);

  // Reset individual order after payment
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E3:E6').setValue(0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is set 'individualOrder' to 0 try:

```
function payment() {
  var individualOrder = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E3:E6').getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i <individualOrder.length ; i++) {
    individualOrder[i]=[0];
  }
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E3:E6').setValues(individualOrder);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this was working with the simpler setValue(0) too. I'm getting an error for the row height when executing the function. It says the row height is only 1, where it needs to be 4.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by making the sum in the spreadsheet and doing a .getValues on that range and using this in .setValues. A lot easier, only 2 lines of code.